# Old subject still used in linked question after typo fix

Tags: bug, hyperlinks, title

In the question : [Recommended ssl_ciphers for security, compatibility - Perfect Forward secrecy](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/54639/recommended-ssl-ciphers-for-security-compatibility-perfect-forward-secrecy) you can see that the question [What are the OpenSSL standard Diffie-Hellman parameters (primes)?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/56214/what-are-the-openssl-standard-diffie-hellman-parameters-primes) is linked but that the wrong question title (one before a typo was fixed: "Hellmann" to "Hellman"). In this very post the second question is linked with the proper title (the correct Hellman instead of Hellmann)

So it seems after a title change something is not updated that should be...

Comment: The dupe answer explains it very well: "It will always insert the current title into the post, at post creation time. However, should the title subsequently change it will not be updated unless the post is edited". So, editing the question will fix the typo.

Comment: Thanks, removing a blank line fixed it. Still very unergonomic and TBH it would be worth it to have the feature to propagate fixes...

Comment: Having the title conversion mechanism be "live" would mean *lots* of extra requests to the server, i.e. lots of wasted bandwidth and overall server load, don't think the rare cases of title edits are worth it. And looking for all existing links when a title is edited is also not very feasible. Maybe there's something in the middle, which won't require extra load on the server or complex development, feel free to start such a feature request. :)

Comment: I was more thinking of a trigger DB or server side, without any schema or API change, which would go one modifying the linking items. Pretty doable if SE already tracks which questions are linked internally.

Comment: The performance impact might still apply, considering [this canonical question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/5963269?lq=1) is linked more than 18000+ times.